# OAuth 2.0 iOS7 not reopening my app

Tags: ios6, oauth-2.0, ios7

I am making a token request to a server, and I have it so the callback URL is example://callback_url and it is parsed for the token information.

In iOS6, this works perfectly,the app loads, checks if there is a token, and if not, loads safari and takes them to the correct URL, you enter in username and password and if it is correct info, loads back my app, and continues correctly.

In iOS7 after the user enters in username and password, the server authenticates the information, but my app is not relaunched. It just tries to load the call_back URL and says no such webpage, instead of loading my app and parsing the info.

Is this just a bug in the beta, or have they changed how you should do the call backs in iOS 7 that im not aware of.

I have tried both of these callbacks, the top one handleOpenURL is deprecated now.

```
//- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
//    [[Auth2Client sharedClient] handleOAuthCallbackWithURL:url];
//    return YES;
//}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    [[Auth2Client sharedClient] handleOAuthCallbackWithURL:url];
    return YES;
}
```

Edit//////

Just adding that i added the URL types adn everything into my plist

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem (after iOs 7 release). Did you find out why it wasn't working?

Comment: No solve yet, I think it has to do with the url Schema being added near the end, and not at the start like http://urlscheme.com/foobar

It needs to be more http://foobar://urlcheama and other things, no luck yet tho.